# Cloning bitbucket repo in local server and project viewed through android studio shows error in all java files

Tags: android, android-studio, git-clone, bitbucket-server

When I am cloning a android project repo from bitbucket everything happens successfully and all files get cloned in my local repo and when I try to open the project by android studio 2.3.3 as the project uploaded was created using android studio 2.3.3 I see everything is okay but when I view any of the java files I see every single thing has an error even all of the import files have error .
I tried cleaning the whole project and rebuilding it which resulted in showing error in every java file now the project will not even build.

what to do now? Please help!

Comment: Try invalidate caches / Restart

Comment: What may be the cause of it ?

Comment: Update your sdk? You might need more dependencies and components.. After that check your gradle file if it shows any warnings,

Comment: the thing I had downloaded the latest sdk and everything after that I had cloned the project cradle file is not showing any warning all of the java files are !

Comment: Did you open the project using Android studio's `Import Project ` option?

Comment: yes I had imported in that way

Comment: Im sorry im at a loss myself. Maybe clone repository again? Different folder?

Comment: Okay let me try